# PrestaShop - Product categories not refreshing on my front-end

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I purchased a new template from themeforest and have a issue.

I added some new categories and in the theme left side bar, the categories name are still the default ones.

I've checked the root category and it is one of my existing categories, anyone can suggest a solution here?

[My store](https://okygraf.com/prestashop/index.php)
[The displayed categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3d8R.png)
[Categories I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPM1i.png)
[Theme preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqYa3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your Smarty cache configuration in the PrestaShop Admin Panel? Try to empty the cache and make sure templates are recompiled properly after any changes.

The module displaying categories in the left column is the `blockcategories` module and it has a Smarty cache mechanism.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer